# plotting a pandas (timeseries) dataframe with errorbars

Tags: python, plot, pandas, time-series, standard-error

I have a pandas dataframe representing several different timeseries of data from regions, subjects and using different measures.  The pandas pivot-table allows me to pivot easily to a particular subset of the data and plot it.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to then add error bars to the plot.  Since the act of pivoting takes the mean or the values for the specified parts of the table, I wrote a little labmda function to make a second table which is perfectly aligned with the first containing the standard error.  However I can't make the plot update by adding error bars with these values.  I believe I could work around by extracting data from the table into vectors, but this defeats the usefulness of the data frame.

sample data:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

# datafile
fileIN = 'model_data.txt' 

# read in data 
data = pd.read_table(fileIN, sep='\t')
```

this data looks like this :

```
In [9]: data.head()
Out[9]: 
  subject     drug group  TR     mask     data         measure
0  sub1S1  placebo    h1   1  region1  0.33333  total_accuracy
1  sub1S1  placebo    h1   1  region1  0.34615            facc
2  sub1S1  placebo    h1   1  region1  0.42308            sacc    
3  sub1S1  placebo    h1   1  region1  0.23077            dacc
4  sub1S1  placebo    h1   1  region1 -0.26923           fdist

# select just what we want to see 
stage1 = data[data['measure'] == 'total_accuracy']
```

this new frame looks like this:

```
In [19]: stage1.head()
Out[19]: 
   subject     drug group  TR     mask     data         measure
0   sub1S1  placebo    h1   1  region1  0.33333  total_accuracy
10  sub1S1  placebo    h1   2  region1  0.39744  total_accuracy
20  sub1S1  placebo    h1   3  region1  0.44872  total_accuracy
30  sub1S1  placebo    h1   4  region1  0.48718  total_accuracy
40  sub1S1  placebo    h1   5  region1  0.48718  total_accuracy
```

the TR, which indicates time, is proceeding as expected.  now, i take the mean over all the session drug and group data i'm not interested in right now, but retain the region data as columns and keep time in rows:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(stage1,values='data',rows=['TR'],cols=['mask'])
```

results in :

```
    mask   region1   region2   region3
TR                                
1     0.302465  0.226020  0.227680
2     0.353040  0.277540  0.329060
3     0.341645  0.340215  0.378680
4     0.354700  0.303180  0.377970
5     0.404085  0.333330  0.320985
6     0.353750  0.409310  0.308165
```

this is great because now when i do

```
ax = table.plot()
```

and set all the attributes i want and then do plt.show(), it's exactly what i want.  however i need to get the errorbars on this graph.  if i do:

```
# lambda function to get standard error
ste = lambda x: np.std(x) / np.sqrt(len(x))
# get a table of the standard errors 
ste_table = pd.pivot_table(stage1,values='data',rows=['TR'],cols=['mask'],aggfunc = ste)
```

then i get:

```
In [26]: ste_table
Out[26]: 
mask   region1   region2   region3
TR                                
1     0.021825  0.014771  0.047511
2     0.031396  0.030384  0.075547
3     0.075713  0.022327  0.049526
4     0.093678  0.048515  0.022832
5     0.058757  0.000000  0.008729
```

which is the correct value of the standard errors.  but i can't find a way to get the plot to update with the errorbars.  as far as i can tell, i could extract the vectors and then plot them using plt.errorbar, but i feel like there should be an easy way to tell the pandas dataframe that these are associated errors and i want them on the plot.  any help is greatly appreciated.  (please excuse the length of this post!  i wanted to explain throughly and i'm a total noob on this forum.  also, stack overflow would not allow me to tag this with errorbars, error bars, or bars)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?